# S3 multipart upload with React JS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload Image/Video files into S3 bucket from my React JS application. So I refered some of the React S3 uploader npm packages [react-dropzone-s3-uploader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone-s3-uploader-multipart) , [react-s3-uploader-multipart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-s3-uploader-multipart).  But both are keep giving Errors while importing into React JS component. And I have already post this error message on my another stack question ([please refer this qus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53206566/typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object-react-js-s3-multipart-fil)). I would like to do this multipart upload directly from my React application to S3 bucket. If anyone knows the solution please share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The only lib which worked perfectly and supported AWS S3 multipart with minimum work was Uppy for me. Highly recommended to try out:

https://uppy.io/docs/aws-s3-multipart/

you will need to provide couple endpoints for it though, so read the docs. You will see "Companion" mentioned there, you can easily ignore it, provide 5 needed endpoints of your custom API and it will be all good. I would suggest to run the UI part, puth in some dummy URLs for these 5 functions and check network activity of the browser to faster understand how it works.

> 1. A function that calls the S3 Multipart API to create a new upload
> 2. A function that calls the S3 Multipart API to list the parts of a file that have already been uploaded
> 3. A function that generates a batch of signed URLs for the specified part numbers
> 4. A function that calls the S3 Multipart API to abort a Multipart upload, and removes all parts that have been uploaded so far
> 5. A function that calls the S3 Multipart API to complete a Multipart upload, combining all parts into a single object in the S3 bucket

Yet no matter what way you would build multipart upload, you will always need to start the upload, list parts, get signed URLs to upload each part, cancel the upload & complete. So it will never be 3 minutes task to build this, but with Uppy i had most of success.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React Dropzone Uploader](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/quick-start), which gives you file previews (including image thumbnails) out of the box, and also handles uploads for you.

Uploads have progress indicators, and they can be cancelled or restarted. The UI is fully customizable.

[Here's an example](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/s3) of how to upload files directly to an S3 bucket, using pre-signed URLs.

Full disclosure: I wrote this library.

Comment: The question is asking specifically about multipart uploads to S3. While your library supports standard S3 uploads, it doesn't seem to support that use case.

Answer (score -1):

Here’s a way to do it full stack MERN with express file upload. Server code here is minimal. This might be helpful, if not, no worries!

https://link.medium.com/U1SdsoHMy2